# Integrating JS with wicket

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, wicket

I have the following js code and html file to generate a responsive table in my page:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTable').dataTable();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>   
<html lang="en">   
<head>   
<meta charset="utf-8">   
<title>Example of Employee Table with twitter bootstrap</title>   
<meta name="description" content="Creating a Employee table with Twitter Bootstrap. Learn with example of a Employee Table with Twitter Bootstrap.">  
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">   
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>  
<body style="margin:20px auto">  
<div class="container">
<div class="row header" style="text-align:center;color:green">
<h3>Bootstrap Table With sorting,searching and paging using dataTable.js (Responsive)</h3>
</div>
<table id="myTable" class="table table-striped" >  
        <thead>  
          <tr>  
            <th>ENO</th>  
            <th>EMPName</th>  
            <th>Country</th>  
            <th>Salary</th>  
          </tr>  
        </thead>  
        <tbody>  
          <tr>  
            <td>001</td>  
            <td>Anusha</td>  
            <td>India</td>  
            <td>10000</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>002</td>  
            <td>Charles</td>  
            <td>United Kingdom</td>  
            <td>28000</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>003</td>  
            <td>Sravani</td>  
            <td>Australia</td>  
            <td>7000</td>  
          </tr>  
        <tr>  
            <td>004</td>  
            <td>Amar</td>  
            <td>India</td>  
            <td>18000</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>005</td>  
            <td>Lakshmi</td>  
            <td>India</td>  
            <td>12000</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>006</td>  
            <td>James</td>  
            <td>Canada</td>  
            <td>50000</td>  
          </tr>  
    
     <tr>  
            <td>007</td>  
            <td>Ronald</td>  
            <td>US</td>  
            <td>75000</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>008</td>  
            <td>Mike</td>  
            <td>Belgium</td>  
            <td>100000</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>009</td>  
            <td>Andrew</td>  
            <td>Argentina</td>  
            <td>45000</td>  
          </tr>  
    
      <tr>  
            <td>010</td>  
            <td>Stephen</td>  
            <td>Austria</td>  
            <td>30000</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>011</td>  
            <td>Sara</td>  
            <td>China</td>  
            <td>750000</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>012</td>  
            <td>JonRoot</td>  
            <td>Argentina</td>  
            <td>65000</td>  
          </tr>  
        </tbody>  
      </table>  
   </div>
</body>  
  </html>
```

When I use it on [here](http://www.compileonline.com/try_html5_online.php) or if I open the .html from the file it works perfectly.

However, if I put it on my wicket project and compile&run, all I get is an table with no pagination, search option etc.

In the wicket project, I surround it with wicket panel like this:

```
<body style="margin:20px auto"><wicket:panel>
```

everything else is pretty much the same.

Comment: Is `$('#myTable').dataTable()` throwing any errors when you are using it in the wicket panel?

Comment: Nope, no errors at all. It is even running on SO as you can see.

Comment: Can you show your wicket code? How you do set the table's id? And how do you pass it to your javascript?

Comment: Hm, interesting point. My table doesn't have a wicket ID. Does every component in html need a wicket ID ?

Comment: @SpiderRico, from your question I can see you are not familiar with Wicket. Please spend some time learning the basics, for example here: https://wicket.apache.org/learn/examples/helloworld.html or  here: http://wicket.apache.org/guide/guide/single.html

Comment: How are your jacascripts loaded? there is a dependency (both dataTables and Bootstrap depend on jQuery), see also 15.5 Resource dependencies at  http://wicket.apache.org/guide/guide/single.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have conflicting JavaScript references. Wicket ships with its own JQuery version (which you can configure with [Application#getJavaScriptLibrarySettings](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/settings/IJavaScriptLibrarySettings.html) -- I'd keep it as is).

First you need to remove all references to CSS and JavaScript libraries from your HTML file, you need to manage those from Java in your page (or panel). Next you need to include them in the proper order (you can create your own ResourceReference for that) in your page or panel by overriding the [renderHead(IHeaderResponse)](https://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/IHeaderContributor.html) method:

```
@Override
public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
    super.renderHead(response);

    response.render(CssHeaderItem.forUrl("http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"));
    response.render(CssHeaderItem.forUrl("http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"));

    // First render the JQuery reference
    response.render(JavaScriptHeaderItem.forReference(getApplication().getJavaScriptLibrarySettings().getJQueryReference()));

    // Then render the dependent JavaScript libraries
    response.render(JavaScriptHeaderItem.forUrl("http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"));
    response.render(JavaScriptHeaderItem.forUrl("http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"));

    // Finally render the dom ready script
    response.render(OnDomReadyHeaderItem.forScript("$('#myTable').dataTable();"));
}
```